# Using Bootcamp to do C# work on Late 2011 Macbook Pro - Runs hot

Tags: windows-8-preview, boot-camp

I expected the battery life to not be as good, but Windows 8 CP seems to kick the fans on very often. I closed out of SQLMS, VS2010, and Zune. It still comes on fairly often and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 had the same with earlier models and Windows 7 as well, never found a true answer - my wild uneducated guess is something in the bootcamp power management drivers is not entirely correct

Comment: Why are you testing against the customer preview?

Comment: What exactly am I testing? I stated that I'm developing an application using Windows 8 CP and was curious why the fans came on so often. Windows 7 isn't going to help me develop Windows 8 apps.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the machine is even running hot. It may just be that the fans are set to kick in at a lower temperature.

Additionally, I would check the CPU/GPU utilization rates. If those are too high, then you can check what is using up all of those resources.